# Error: 'tensorflow_recommenders' has no attribute 'metrics'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I follow this [post](https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/basic_retrieval) of Google to try a practical recommend system with TensorFlow.

This is my Python code:

```
import os
import pprint
import tempfile

from typing import Dict, Text

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow_recommenders as tfrs

# Ratings data.
ratings = tfds.load("movielens/100k-ratings", split="train")
# Features of all the available movies.
movies = tfds.load("movielens/100k-movies", split="train")

ratings = ratings.map(lambda x: {
    "movie_title": x["movie_title"],
    "user_id": x["user_id"],
})
movies = movies.map(lambda x: x["movie_title"])
tf.random.set_seed(42)

shuffled = ratings.shuffle(100_000, seed=42, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)
train = shuffled.take(80_000)
test = shuffled.skip(80_000).take(20_000)

movie_titles = movies.batch(1_000)
user_ids = ratings.batch(1_000_000).map(lambda x: x["user_id"])

unique_movie_titles = np.unique(np.concatenate(list(movie_titles)))

unique_user_ids = np.unique(np.concatenate(list(user_ids)))
unique_movie_titles[:10]

embedding_dimension = 32

user_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(
      vocabulary=unique_user_ids, mask_token=None),
  tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(unique_user_ids) + 1, embedding_dimension)
])

movie_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(
      vocabulary=unique_movie_titles, mask_token=None),
  tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(unique_movie_titles) + 1, embedding_dimension)
])


metrics = tfrs.metrics.FactorizedTopK(
  candidates=movies.batch(128).map(movie_model)
)
```

After running above code, I received an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mducc1412/Documents/Project/Persional/Movielens/tensorflow_recommenders.py", line 10, in <module>
    import tensorflow_recommenders as tfrs
  File "/Users/mducc1412/Documents/Project/Persional/Movielens/tensorflow_recommenders.py", line 141, in <module>
    metrics = tfrs.metrics.FactorizedTopK(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'tensorflow_recommenders' has no attribute 'metrics' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

My enviroment:

- MacOS 14.0
- Python 3.9
- Pip 23.2.1
- TensorFlow 2.14.0
- tensorflow_recommenders 0.7.3
- tensorflow_datasets 4.9.3

Comment: @Qiu I am aware of the file name problem